# Does anyone know what happened to nowinchess.com?

Tags: websites

I used to go to the http://www.nowinchess.com/ website to see what are the new tournaments, and grab PGN files of past tournaments. It was simple, and excellent. Suddenly, two weeks ago another content appeared, not in English... Does anyone have any idea what happened?

Comment: "No win chess" is actually the name of a chess site? Sounds like the way I play. No thanks!

Comment: or is it "Now In Chess"? :)

Answer (score 1):

They are rebuildin the site. You could find the tournaments in nowinchess.com/wp/live.

Probably you should write a comment to ask them to translate the site.
If you need help I can do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

There wasn't any upload after middle of the year 2013. When I was there last September I already had the feeling that the service has stopped.

Comment: But I only recently (2-3 weeks ago) downloaded some new PGN files from there...